# Use k8s port forwarding in current process

Tags: elasticsearch, go, tcp, kubernetes

I would like to port-forward a TCP connection to my program and use it to communicate with the pod. I am able to establish a connection to the pod and to execute a curl on `http://localhost:9200/` from a different shell.
However, when trying to reach the service from within my program, I am getting a connection refused.

Here is my snippet to establish the connection and make a local curl.

```
stopChan, readyChan := make(chan struct{}, 1), make(chan struct{}, 1)
out, errOut := new(bytes.Buffer), new(bytes.Buffer)
path := fmt.Sprintf("/api/v1/namespaces/%s/pods/%s/portforward", "default", "my-http-server")
hostIP := strings.TrimLeft(config.Host, "https://")
serverURL := url.URL{Scheme: "https", Path: path, Host: hostIP}

dialer := spdy.NewDialer(upgrader, &http.Client{Transport: roundTripper}, http.MethodGet, &serverURL)
forwarder, err := portforward.New(dialer, []string{flagPort}, stopChan, readyChan, out, errOut)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

/* From here, I can make a curl to http://localhost:9200/ from a different shell */

/* But I can't curl from within this process */
resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:9200/")
if err != nil {
    /* It is exiting here */
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(resp.Status, resp.Body)
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

I am getting: `panic: dial tcp [::1]:9200: connect: connection refused`

Should I reuse the dialer that I have setup to communicate with the pod?
Ideally, I will need to reuse this connection with the [Elasticsearch client](https://godoc.org/github.com/olivere/elastic#NewClient)
Why do I get refused on both `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` as it is working fine outside of that process?

Comment: Can you post your kubernetes deployment/service? Also, are you executing the go program from inside the cluster?

Comment: My logic from before this snippet is able to fetch the right port and pod, which I can also hardcode so this is fine. This program is executed from my laptop, outside from the kubernetes cluster and is using my local kubeconfig to establish the connection with the cluster. By the way, the connection to the cluster is fine as I can list and describe the pod. I believe the issue is that the network level here..

Comment: The issue is that you don't have anything on your laptop that would provide access to the pod through your laptop's localhost:9200. You'll need some kind of port forwarding _on_ _your_ _laptop_ for this to work. An ssh -L 9200:whatever could be one solution.

Comment: But isn't the proxy made from within the program already (cf snippet)? Since I can `curl http://localhost:9200` from a different shell once I get it running, it means that the port forwarding from Kubernetes API is working

Answer (score 0):

You can try using go-routine to do port forwarding and accessing it in same program.

```
go func(){
//Port Forward logic
}()
//Access it.
```